# Using etree, how can I get all text of an element and its child elements with their tags in an HTML file?

Tags: python, html, xml

I'm trying to get text data from HTML files and reformat them according to their tags. The HTML file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>

(some HTML code)

<section id="descrption">

    descrption_text_0

    <span class="ac"><span class="ac">1a.</span></span>

    descrption_text_1

    <i>italic_0</i>

    <span class="ac"><span class="ac">1b.</span></span>

    descrption_text_2

    <i>italic_1</i>

</section>

(some other HTML code)

</html>
```

My goal is to generate a list of data containing all text and their tags inside the "section" tag, keeping them in the same order as they are in the original HTML code, which should look like this:

```
[('section', 'descrption_text_0'),
 ('ac', '1a.'),
 ('section', 'descrption_text_1'),
 ('i', 'italic_0'),
 ('ac', '1b.'),
 ('section', 'descrption_text_2'),
 ('i', 'italic_1')]
```

And here is what I tried so far:

```
html = etree.HTML(my_html_file)

# this returns a list of all text without their tags
html.xpath('//section[@id="description"]//text()')

# this only gets texts inside the children of <section>, without "descrption_text_0", "descrption_text_0", etc
for el in html.iter():
    if el.tag == 'section' and el.attrib['id'] == 'description':
    print(el.tag)
    print(el.text)
    for sub_el in el.iter():
        print(sub_el.tag)
        print(sub_el.text)
```

The last method I could think of is to convert it back to raw HTML code using etree.trostring(), and write another function to deal with it... but is there any way to achieve my goal using the built-in funcitons of etree? Or is there any other module that can do this? Thanks in advance.